# How can i place my sticky side-nav inside my section but make it scrollable for all sections?

Tags: html, css, sidenav

i want a sticky side nav. I have three sections and place the nev in my first section but it just sticks till the end of the first section.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="sections">
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <nav id="my-navigation">
                <div id="container">
                    <li><a href="">Start.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My work.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Skills.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Education.</a></li>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section2"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}

.section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#section1 {
    background-color: grey;
}

#section2 {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

#section3 {
    background-color: brown;
}

#my-navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    position: sticky;
    height: 75vh;
    top: calc(25vh/2);
    left: 30px;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    height: inherit;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#container > li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

I already tried to place the nav before the first section like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="sections">
        <nav id="my-navigation">
            <div id="container">
                <li><a href="">Start.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">My work.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Skills.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Education.</a></li>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="section" id="section1"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section2"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But the result was not what i expected.

[image: There is now a white space before my first section]

Is there a possibility to place the nav somehow independent? It just should be sticky for the whole website.

Comment: Check out flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

A solution which uses [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for the global layout and [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for the navigation links, just to show how to use these two – Grid is two-dimensional, Flex is one-dimensional.

Yes, we could also have used Flex for the global layout here, but using Grids has a pragmatic advantage: There are [nice tools](https://grid.layoutit.com/) available to create them visually.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing:border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
      }

      body {
        display: grid;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        gap: 0px 0px;
        grid-template-areas:
          "navi content";
      }
      
        nav {
          grid-area: navi;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          gap: 10px;
          margin: auto 30px;
          padding:0 1em;
          border-left: 2px solid #000;
          max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
          overflow-y: auto;
        }
        
          nav a {
            display:block;
          }

        main {
          grid-area: content;
          overflow-y:auto;
        }

          section {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
          }
          .s1 { background: grey; }
          .s2 { background: aquamarine; }
          .s3 { background: brown; }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="">Start.</a>
      <a href="">My work.</a>
      <a href="">Skills.</a>
      <a href="">Education.</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <section class="s1"></section>
      <section class="s2"></section>
      <section class="s3"></section>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice man, thank you for that work. I never worked with grids, very interesting.
But in my case i dont want a section for the nav. I want that nav on top of my sections, so that the navs background are the sections. The nav should be the highest layer and on top of the sections.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the solution in my case is just basically to use position: fixed instead of position: sticky. Took me hours to remember there is this option, but worked for me.

```
#my-navigation {
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
height: 75vh;
top: calc(25vh/2);
left: 30px;
border-left: 2px solid #000;}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was also what I was going to suggest, but you have found it out yourself.

Comment: If you have to put text elements in your sections you'll still have to deal with positioning those to keep them from going behind nav.